# Creating activity with layout defined in runtime in android application

Tags: android, android-activity, runtime

Usually the activity has a predefined layout which is described in the xml file. What if I know the exact number and types of UI elements only during the runtime?(for example, I need to display as many TextBoxes as user defined) Is it possible to create an activity with a layout defined during runtime and if it is, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set an identifier to a view, where you want to insert your views at runtime :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout" 
    ... >
```

Then you can add child views to this LinearLayout programatically, whenever you want :

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
linearLayout.removeAllViews();

// Add a TextView (it could be any kind of View)
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("...");
linearLayout.addView(textView);
```

Comment: when I add views, they all are in one line. When I'm trying to define LayoutParams to FILL_PARENT for each element, they are still in one line and only first is shown

Comment: What about `<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
setContentView(layout);
```

This layout you can define during runtime